# Why will my code read a file when run on netbeans but not when run on CMD?

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

My code is working fine and exactly as its supposed to on netbeans but when I use the CMD it doesn't execute everything like it does on netbeans. The first try/catch is supposed to count the number of times it reads something on a txt file. On netbeans it works fine but on the CMD it keeps the declared value of 0.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class Calories {


public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException {



    String file = "input.txt";
    String text = "";
    double [] breakfast = new double [7];
    double [] lunch = new double [7];
    double [] dinner = new double [7];
    int counter = 0;


    try {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

       while(input.hasNextInt()) {
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(number);
        counter++;
    }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    //If the file is missing a number or has an extra the program will tell the user and will exit
    if (counter != 21) {
        System.out.println("Counter " + counter);
        System.out.println("Your file will not work with this program. Please try again.");
            System.exit(0);
    }

    //this is going to attempt to read from file "input.txt"
    //if file cannot be found user will be told the it cannot be found 
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(file));
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            for (int i = 0;i<7;i++)
            {
                breakfast[i] = s.nextInt();
                lunch[i] = s.nextInt();
                dinner[i] = s.nextInt();


            }

        }

    }

    //this catch will execute if the file name is incorrect

    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }



    //calling all of the methods I created here

    getCal(breakfast, lunch, dinner);
    getDays(breakfast, lunch, dinner);
    getAvg(breakfast, lunch, dinner);
    //exits program once it has finished executing the methods
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I've tried everything to my knowledge but I still cannot figure this out.

Comment: Wait. It doesn't execute? or it doesn't compile? Please be clear on this since your question mentions both. If it's an execution problem, what exception / error messages do you see?

Comment: I have to wonder if it's due to where Java is looking for your file, where the "user.dir" is, and that you're probably better off using resources and not files.

Comment: My apologies, it does execute however in that first try/catch its supposed to read through a file and count each time it reads something. In netbeans it executes fine but on the command it keeps the counter at its initial value 0.

Comment: And you'll never know why with code like this: `catch (Exception ex) {  }`. Please don't do this to yourself. At least print out the stacktrace: `ex.printStacktrace():`

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the thousands of similar questions. Please search this site a little deeper and you'll find them. Then use resources (as the answers will show you) and not Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running it from command line then your code expects `input.txt` file to be in the same directory from where you are running the `java [PROGRAM_NAME] [FILE_NAME]` command

If you place this file in the same directory it will work fine.

On the other hand Netbeans handle it itself that is the resolution of the file path if you place it in the project root directory for example.

`"input.txt"` This name is not telling you anything about where the file is placed. It is upto the Netbeans or command line where they try to find this file.

If you use project resources path or something like a relative path it will try to find there and it will have an info where to find the file.

Similarly if you will put an absolute path for the file the file will be searched in that path.

But here you have not provided any information about the path.

Comment: This was it. Thanks a bunch.